# Is there a shortcut to close source tabs in the devtools debugger?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

As pictured here, I'm wondering if there is a keyboard shortcut to close these tabs either one by one or in bulk

[image: devtools source tabs]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> or <kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> (Mac) to close the active tab. See [Sources panel keyboard shortcuts](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts#sources).
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> then type `clo` and it'll show you "Close All" command.

  [image: close all in the command menu]
- Right-click a tab name > select **Close all**.

  [image: close all]

Comment: This is not working in M1 mac for some reason?

Comment: alt+w doesn't work in mac brave